# OpenVPN over SSh port forwarding : can't redirect all trafic through VPN

Tags: macos, routing, port-forwarding, openvpn, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to escape my university wifi network rules with my Macbook (OSX 10.10).

The university allows us to use a server, say bastion.univ.com, to mount an ssh port forwarding.
I've an OpenVPN server running at home (tunnelblick).

On client : I mount an ssh port to forward my VPN packets, then I connect to VPN. Everything works fine if I don't use `redirect-gateway def1`, ie when I don't redirect all traffic through the VPN (tests done : I can route manually some traffic, `route add -net ...`). If I use def1, the connection doesn't work and the ssh process that keeps my port open ends brutally.

I supposed that, as I tell the OpenVPN client to redirect all traffic, it tries to redirect the trafic before passing by the ssh port. And so it doesn't work.

How can I configure the client to use my VPN server to redirect all traffic (or a list of domains as github.com, sf.com, etc.) but still using the ssh port ?

EDIT :

I've just try to add a rule in order to redirect all traffic except for the SSH server :

```
#redirect all trafic through VPN
redirect-gateway def1

#except the ssh port forward
allow-pull-fqdn #allow use of domaine names in route
route bastion.univ.com 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

It's all working now !

Comment: You have to do what `redirect-gateway` does for your SSH server too: Add an explicit route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add an explicit route for the SSH server traffic to not go through VPN as said by @daniel-b :

```
#redirect all trafic through VPN
redirect-gateway def1

#except the ssh port forward
allow-pull-fqdn #allow use of domaine names in route
route bastion.univ.com 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```